# C# Find Attribute in XML with another Attribute with Descendants

Tags: c#, xml, search, attributes

First I want to find and select the `PID"5678"` from the `<Tool>`. With help of this PID, i want to find and select the `ID"5678"` from the `<Parent>`. The PID and the ID are the same value, but I have to find it from the `<Tool>` first.
At the moment I have following Code, to select the first PID. How can I "copy" this value and search with them the Attribute "ID"?

```
List<string> urls = xmldoc2.Descendants("PID").Select(x => x.Attribute("5678").Value).ToList();



<Tools>
   <Tools>
      <Tool>
        <ID>1234</ID>
        <PID>5678</PID>
        <Name>Test</Name>
      </Tool>
  </Tools>
  <Type>
    <Parent>
      <ID>5678</ID>
      <PID>9999</PID>
      <Name>Test2</Name>
    </Parent>
  </Type>
</Tools>
```

Comment: You need to do it in two steps.  First parse xml for both Tool and Parent.  Then get parent.  You really have a two step compiler application.  First step is to get the definitions.  Second step is to process the data.  Basic Computer Science Algorithm.  CS201.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that your Xml has multiple Root nodes - which does not work well.
So wrap it into single parent node (i.e. "Root" in below example)
Something of this sort should help you.

string xmlData = @"... Your Xml here....";

```
        var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlData);


        var pidNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//Root/Tools/Tools/Tool/PID");

        foreach(XmlNode node in pidNodes)
        {
            var typeNodeForPid = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//Root/Type/Parent[ID = '{0}']", node.InnerText));
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, but its a very big XML i have with many nodes. Isnt it possible to do it with descendants? I think with .SelectSingleNode, it isnt possible